# What should the Kth ant do in the Ant Colony Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I'm new to this community so hope I get this question answered. I have been trying to code the Ant Colony Optimization Algorithm in C++ but I'm not getting the idea. This is what I get about the algorithm: -First, an ant starts at the origin (main city) of the graph until it reaches the target. -Then, another ant is launched. But what happens then? I mean, the ant follows the trail or the ants keeps picking the edges randomly? I mean, I don't know how to code and give the ant more probability to pick an edge instead of another one.

Could someone help me with this? I have read the wiki link a thousand times but still not getting the idea and it's not easy to understand because I haven't studied probability.

Thanks

Comment: I remember putting this comment on another question like this (was it yours? did you delete and repost it? A better solution is to edit your question, which will bump it). The comment was something like: The ant probabilistically choses from paths, and paths with stronger scents are weighed higher. It's random, but weighted.

Comment: Yes, I shouldn't have deleted the post. Sorry. Could you try to help me ?

Comment: It's weighted but how do I weight an edge in C++? I mean, for me would be something like this:
More pheromones than the others ? Take that edge. 
Less Pheromones than the others ? Don't take that edge.

Answer (score 3):

The idea behind the ant colony algorithm is that

1) all edges start out with no scent

2) an ant taking an edge gives it some extra scent

3) scent decays over time

4) if an ant has multiple paths to pick from, it picks randomly - BUT - randomly with weights according to scent quantity on each path.

Picture it like this.

Let's says that a road with no scent has weight 1, and a road with scent units 1 has weight 2.

An ant sees four paths, but the first path has one scent unit.

The weights are: 2, 1, 1, 1

Total weight = 5

Chance of taking path one = 2/5 (40%)

Chance of taking path two = 1/5 (same for path three, four and five) (20%, 20%, 20%)

Obviously you can use whatever functions you like for how much scent is added to an edge dependent upon how much scent it has, how much scent decays dependent upon how much scent it has, and how much scent weighs (and if anything else can cause a path to be weighed, such as a static evaluation function)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Patashu, but isn't the second ant going to pick the all the paths that the first ant chose?

Comment: @Rgon No. In my example, it has only a 40% chance.

Comment: And how do you represent a chance in C++?

Comment: @Rgon Find the total number of weight, roll a random number between 0 and (totalweight), and add weights until the next weight would push you above your roll - take the path of the weight you were about to add.

Comment: I don't understand. Maybe some seudocode would help me or try to explain it with an example.

Comment: @Rgon It's just this algorithm. http://peterkellyonline.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/weighted-random-selection-in-php.html

Comment: Hmm... I couldn't understand the sintax and so the idea.

Comment: Can we move to something like a chat so you can explain me better?

Comment: @Rgon There really isn't anything I can say about the algorithm I haven't already covered. It is very simple and very transparent about how it works.

Comment: Dammit... and I don't speak English so I can understand you better... Could you share me a video explaining this subject in programming?

Comment: Hmm would it be something like this.

The city -A- has three paths. And the ant picks the path C. The next will have to choose between this:
-A-C-C-B. 
Then we pick a random between those.

Comment: @Rgon Yes, that is the general idea, and now you generalize it such that different path scents weigh different amounts besides just 1 and 2 (you can even do fractional amounts, etc)